# Adding ripple effect in buttons for API 9+

Tags: android, eclipse, effect, ripple

Almost all of the ways I've found to add the ripple effect to the button (when pressed) are for API 21.
I've found something in github that supports API 9+ but it requires to use Maven (and Gradle ..).
Now , I'm working with Eclipse, not android studio. Can I still use it? and how?

Thank you.

Comment: "I'm working with Eclipse, not android studio" -- you should consider budgeting the time to move off of Eclipse by the end of the year, as Google will no longer be supporting Eclipse-based app development at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use it - clone the repo locally and reference it from your code OR download the lib jar itself and put it in your libs folder. The only downside working like this is that you need to keep up with lib updates manually.

Comment: I tried that..
When I try to import the package I get:
`The import com.andexert cannot be resolved`